# Node.js Code Change Not Reflected in Localhost Browser Unless Webstorm is Restarted

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

I've spent a day on this already.  Because I can't continue to develop code if I have to keep restarting webstorm every time I make a node.js code change.

**Here is a 1 minute screen cast of my problem**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xg_k8M0VwBI and here are my webstorm settings https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hX3I1AWMLT8

**A few initial facts**:

- I'm using Webstorm 10.0.3
- I'm using nodemon which watches my code and stops and starts (creates a new node process) after I make changes to code
- I've got my debugger | Live Edit set to Auto in Preferences.  I tried manual but it didn't make any difference in terms of my problem below

**Here is what is happening**:

1. I open webstorm (lets say it was already closed)
2. I run debug on my express.js app and it fires up fine meaning I can go to localhost:3000 and it loads fine
3. I make a breaking change to code such as what you see in the video above
4. I refresh the browser page, now I get a 404 error and that's actually expected because I broke the code with the breaking change I made
5. I now go back and undo that breaking change, back to where the code was working before
6. I refresh debug or click debug again or whatever
7. I refresh the browser, but still it's a 404, this makes no sense!
8. I ultimately have to restart Webstorm (including the invalidate cache) and start it up again for the localhost:3000 to load without the 404 error after making that change back to working code

I can't believe this happens.  I can't believe I'm the only one who has seen this problem.  But I also can't believe I can't resolve this!  is this a bug?  I'm using Webstorm 10.0.3.

I'm simply changing these lines of code for example:

This code works if I fire up Webstorm (previously closed):

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express web server is listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

This breaks it causing a 404 (because there's a missing end bracket after get('port' but the JS is valid in terms of no errors because I put an ending bracket at the end:

```
app.listen(app.get('port', function(){
    console.log('Express web server is listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
}));
```

Comment: just for referencing: problem was caused by ws built-in server port set in preferences. https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/465005?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

at 0:45 there seem to be a new debugger tab. 
I don't have webstorm to confirm the workflow, but it is possible that the two debuggers tabs compete on the same port 3000 at some point the debugger with the broken code stays a live regardless of future changes that might try to apply on the 2nd instance which is not really being served.

my suggestion is see if you can maintain a single debugger instance(tab) and see if that solve it for you.

[image]

Comment: you might want to consider reporting this to webstorm support.

Comment: yea I probably will do that next.  Super frustrating.